# WPBakery displays a blank settings pop-up windows when editing an item on the page

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I am using wordpress 5.8.2 and I have problem with WPBackery (version 6.4.1) page editor.
As soon as I want to edit any element of my page, I get the popup windows element setting blank without nothing inside. I have the problem with all my browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Brave, ..). I have also the same problem on different wordpress servers.

What could be the solution to solve this problem ?

[image: as illustrated here]

Answer (score 1):

I have upgraded the WPBakery plugin in version 6.7.0, and the problem still remains.. but I have found that there is a conflict problem between **WPBackery Plugin** and **Essential Grid Plugin** (version 3.0.7). If I deactivate the Essential Grid Plugin, then WPBakery is working fine and I can edit my pages. As soon I activate Essential Grid Plugin, it is impossible to edit my pages with WPBakery. This problem has been issued since 2018 [wpbakery essentialgrid conflict](https://seventhqueen.com/support/forums/topic/wpbakery-page-builder-conflict-with-essential-grid), but unfortunately, I don't find any solution which solves this conflict between these two plugins.

Comment: I too am facing the same problem. did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings > Permalinks. Click Save without changing any settings, then check if the problem is fixed. For some reason, this worked for me.